# ExecutorCompletionService: why queue results as Future's

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to find a reason why the class ExecutorCompletionService queues results as `Future<T>` and not as `T` only.

According to [its API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html#take()) `take()`

> "Retrieves and removes the Future representing the next completed task, waiting if none are yet present".

Therefore, the call to `future.get()` will never block, because the product generated by the task is 100% completed.

Why encapsulate that product in a `Future` then?

Answer (score 4):

Well for one thing, the `Future<T>` returned on `submit()` still has some possibilities you don't have with just the `T` such as `cancel()`, `isDone()` as well as `get( long timeOut...)` etc., so while you could argue that `take()` could return `T` it could also be argued that it's cleaner and more flexible to return the `Future<T>` instead.

And in particular, it gives the callee the possibility to determine if the `Callable` was completed or cancelled (which is the TL;DR answer)

Cheers,

Comment: I think it makes sense that submit returns a `Future<T>`, because the task doesn't have to be finished inmediatly. But in the case of take, we are 100% that the task is completed, so calling `future.get()` seems like an unnecesary overhead (I don't think anybody calls `cancel` in that case). Anyway, I figure out that returning `Future<T>` in `take()` is due to consistency with the rest of the API, although I would be happy if somebody could give a different reason :)

Comment: I'm not sure that the result can be put in the completed tasks queue if the task has been cancelled, as you mention. Sorry if I'm wrong about that, if a cancelled task can be put in that queue that would be a good reason to use `Future<T>`